# How should I pass `cardNumberElement`, `cardExpiryElement` and `cardCvcElement` into `stripe.confirmCardPayment`'s `payment_method.card`?

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

In stripe docs, I can easily create a card like this

```js
var cardElement = elements.create("card");
```

And I simpliy pass the `cardElement` to `confirmCardPayment`

```js
stripe.confirmCardPayment("{PAYMENT_INTENT_CLIENT_SECRET}", {
  payment_method: {
    card: cardElement,
  },
});
```

However, for **visual style css** reason, I have to split `cardElement` in to three pieces like this:

```js
var cardNumberElement = elements.create("cardNumber");
var cardExpiryElement = elements.create("cardExpiry");
var cardCvcElement = elements.create("cardCvc");
```

Then I want to call `stripe.confirmCardPayment`, what should I do right now?

[The doc](https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_intents/confirm_card_payment) only shows `cardElement` method, no splitted example.

Comment: I found an example at https://github.com/stripe/react-stripe-js/blob/b14c6bddadec30d46772dc668897982293bdd57d/examples/hooks/2-Split-Card.js#L52-L67

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can pass the CardNumber Element in. As long as they were all created from the same instance of the Elements object, the confirmCardPayment function will pull the relevant information from all of the mounted Elements to get the expiry/CVC too and it will just work.

```
stripe.confirmCardPayment("{PAYMENT_INTENT_CLIENT_SECRET}", {
  payment_method: {
    card: cardNumberElement,
  },
});
```

https://stripe.com/docs/js/setup_intents/confirm_card_setup#stripe_confirm_card_setup-with_element-payment_method-card

Comment: This is not a good answer, look at the other answers.

Comment: Blows my mind that they don't explain this somewhere in the docs (that it automatically picks up the other fields).

Answer (score 7):

Cardholder name and ZIP / postal code can be submitted the following way (using regular input elements):

```
stripe.confirmCardPayment("{PAYMENT_INTENT_CLIENT_SECRET}", {
  payment_method: {
    card: cardNumberElement,
    billing_details: {
       name: document.getElementById("inputCardholderName").value,
       address: {
          postal_code: document.getElementById("inputZip").value
       }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: It was astonishingly hard to find this anywhere else on the Internet!

Answer (score 7):

**karllekko's** answer works.

In case you are using the
CardNumberElement,
CardExpiryElement,
CardCvcElement,
components from '@stripe/react-stripe-js'

you can simply do:

```
payment_method: {
        card: elements.getElement(CardNumberElement), 
        .
        .
}
```

and it will automatically fetch the other component's values.

Comment: I can't find any official docs stating this. And in my testing, it seems that there is no validation preventing me from passing an Amex card number but a 3-digit (and therefore invalid) CVC. So my form tries to submit. But of course no payment method gets created.

Comment: A Stripe rep told me on Discord that Amex can sometimes have 3-digit CVC. I have found no documented proof of this online, but maybe it's true.