# How to use list of elements for Stripe confirmCardPayment

Tags: api, sdk, stripe-payments, element, payment

As per [Stripe Doc](https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_intents/confirm_card_payment), **payment_method.card** accepts an object as value, which the documentation uses **cardElement**.

```
stripe
  .confirmCardPayment('{PAYMENT_INTENT_CLIENT_SECRET}', {
    payment_method: {
      card, // Uses the mounted card element
      billing_details: {
        name: 'Jenny Rosen',
      },
    },
  })
  .then(function(result) {
    // Handle result.error or result.paymentIntent
  });
```

How can I replicate the same method, using a list of elements instead of a single cardElement?

**Instead of...**

```
const card = elements.create('card');
card.mount('#card-element');
```

**I'd like to use...**

```
const cardNumber = elements.create('cardNumber')
cardNumber.mount('#card-number')

const cardExpiry = elements.create('cardExpiry')
cardExpiry.mount('#card-expiry')

const cardCvc = elements.create('cardCvc')
cardCvc.mount('#card-cvc')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I pass \`cardNumberElement\`, \`cardExpiryElement\` and \`cardCvcElement\` into \`stripe.confirmCardPayment\`'s \`payment\_method.card\`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62171886/how-should-i-pass-cardnumberelement-cardexpiryelement-and-cardcvcelement)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you use the same instance of `elements` to create and mount all of the separate card elements, you can pass any of the mounted  card parts to `confirmCardPayment()`. Stripe.js will group them together automatically. So for example:

```
stripe
  .confirmCardPayment('{PAYMENT_INTENT_CLIENT_SECRET}', {
    payment_method: {
      cardNumber, // Uses the mounted card element
      billing_details: {
        name: 'Jenny Rosen',
      },
    },
  })
  .then(function(result) {
    // Handle result.error or result.paymentIntent
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

A small correction to teh above. Without mentioning 'card' as the key for the object, it seems to fail randomly.  The following works everytime

```
stripe
  .confirmCardPayment('{PAYMENT_INTENT_CLIENT_SECRET}', {
    payment_method: {
      card : cardNumber, //corrected here
      billing_details: {
        name: 'Jenny Rosen',
      },
    },
  })
  .then(function(result) {
    // Handle result.error or result.paymentIntent
  });
```

Comment: I found an example here: https://github.com/stripe/react-stripe-js/blob/b14c6bddadec30d46772dc668897982293bdd57d/examples/hooks/2-Split-Card.js#L52-L67